# Angular CLI CSS Not Working

Tags: angular-cli

Using Angular CLI, I've been working through a Udemy course on Angular 2.  Unfortunately, the instructor doesn't use CLI, so I may be missing something, but my app doesn't seem to apply any CSS styling.  Given that CLI automatically includes `styleUrls: ['app.component.css']` in the root component as well as creates that CSS file, I wouldn't think it would be a syntax error with the routing, but I don't know for sure.  Here's the link to my code:  https://github.com/mrmikemcguire/Udemy-directives and thanks in advance.

Comment: Having the same issue - I just added a simple like like "body { background-color: red } and it shows nothing in the final page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed your repo your directives shouldn't have templates if you create your views inside of your root components html then your css implementation will work.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html

There are no templates for directives in general.